# Why is const lost in this template structure?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

It is known that the following function pointers have different types:

```
void foo_int_ref(int&);
void foo_const_int_ref(const int&);

static_assert(
    !std::is_same<
        decltype(foo_int_ref),
        decltype(foo_const_int_ref)
    >::value,
    "Types should be different");
```

Let's consider this generalization:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T t) {}

template<typename T>
struct ref_vs_const_ref {
    typedef decltype(foo<T>) foo_T;
    typedef decltype(foo<const T>) foo_const_T;
};

using int_ref_vs_const_ref = ref_vs_const_ref<int&>;

static_assert(
    !std::is_same<
        typename int_ref_vs_const_ref::foo_T,
        typename int_ref_vs_const_ref::foo_const_T
    >::value,
    "Types should be different"); // -- it fails
```

The last assertion fails. For some reason, the `const` is lost for `foo_const_T`. But why?

Comment: When `T` is a reference type, `const T` is just the same as `T` ([\[dcl.ref\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#1.sentence-3)). In `const int&`, `const` applies to `int`, not to `int&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `const` on value parameters does *not* affect the signature in any shape or form. The same is true when you remove the reference from the non-template declarations. The `const` only affects the use of the parameter in the function definition. If you add a reference or a pointer to the type things change and the `const` affects the type of the function.

In your nested types the `T` is a `int&` to which the `const` is applied. However, `T&` and `T& const` are also the same types. I guess your confusion stems from your ill-advised placement of `const` to the left: it is more the `const` applies to the top-level entity.

Comment: @ivaigult - `const T` is not transformed to `const int&`, just like it wouldn't transform to `const int*` for `T = int*`.

Comment: @ivaigult: `const T` does *not* transform to `const int&` but to `int& const` when `T` is `int&`.

Comment: `int& const x = y` doesnt event compile, what does this mean?

Comment: @AnkurSharma Yes, you can’t write `T& const` as references are already immutable. The point I’m making is that a `const X` where `X` is a type alias for `T&` isn’t the same as `const T&` (or `T const&` when placing the `const` properly to the right). Instead, the `const X` and `X` are identical ([here](https://godbolt.org/z/f1G5eG4W8) is a Compiler Explorer link).

Answer (score 1):

The answer of "why" this is happening has been already given. This is a possible way to resolve your problem -- adding "const" to the nested type:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct add_value_const
{
    using type = const T;
};

template<typename T>
using add_value_const_t = typename add_value_const<T>::type;

template<typename T>
struct add_value_const<
    T, std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_reference<T>::value
    >
>
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
        add_value_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>&,
        add_value_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>&&
    >;
};

template<typename T>
struct add_value_const<
    T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value>
>
{
    using type = add_value_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>*;
};
```

In your case you would have to use `foo<add_value_const<T>>` instead of `foo<const T>`.

I used the C++14 syntax, but it could be ported easily to C++11. With C++17 it is even more readable.

You can find the compiling example [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/XxayJc).